# Jetbrains Exposed ORM DuplicateColumnException

Tags: postgresql, kotlin, kotlin-exposed

I am trying out the Exposed ORM, but I get the following error which, my poor eyes cannot find the reason for:

> Exception in thread "main"
> org.jetbrains.exposed.exceptions.DuplicateColumnException: Duplicate
> column name "name" in table "Venues"

```
object Organizations: IntIdTable() {
    val name: Column<String> = varchar("name", 255)
    val email: Column<String> = varchar("email", 255)
}

object Venues: IntIdTable() {
    val name: Column<String> = varchar("name", 255)
    val address: Column<String> = varchar("address", 255)
    val organizationId = reference("organizationId", Organizations)
}

object Spaces: IntIdTable() {
    val name: Column<String> = varchar("name", 255)
    val capacity: Column<Int> = integer("capacity")
    val type: Column<Int> = integer("type")
    val venue = reference("venueId", Venues)
}

object DatabaseFactory {
    private val appConfig = ConfigFactory.load()
    private val dbUrl = appConfig.getString("db.jdbcUrl")
    private val dbUser = appConfig.getString("db.dbUser")
    private val dbPassword = appConfig.getString("db.dbPassword")

    fun init() {
        val database = Database.connect(hikari())
        transaction(database) {
            // create tables if missing
            SchemaUtils.create(
                Organizations,
                Venues,
                Spaces
            )
        }
    }

    private fun hikari(): HikariDataSource {
        val config = HikariConfig()
        config.driverClassName = "org.postgresql.Driver"
        config.jdbcUrl = dbUrl
        config.username = dbUser
        config.password = dbPassword
        config.maximumPoolSize = 3
        config.isAutoCommit = false
        config.transactionIsolation = "TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ"
        config.validate()
        return HikariDataSource(config)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the name of the table at each object definition

```
object Organizations: IntIdTable("organizations") {
    val name: Column<String> = varchar("name", 255)
    val email: Column<String> = varchar("email", 255)
}

object Venues: IntIdTable("venues") {
    val name: Column<String> = varchar("name", 255)
    val address: Column<String> = varchar("address", 255)
    val organizationId = reference("organizationId", Organizations)
}

object Spaces: IntIdTable("spaces") {
    val name: Column<String> = varchar("name", 255)
    val capacity: Column<Int> = integer("capacity")
    val type: Column<Int> = integer("type")
    val venue = reference("venueId", Venues)
}
```